# Application Master is running beyond physical memory limits without obvious reason

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, memory, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark.

Previously i had a similar problem, I collected a lot of data in driver program and didn't realize that lineage of dataframe kept source of data in driver until action was completed. A solution of this problem was to checkpoint dataframe (so lineage became lazy sourced).

But recently I met the same problem, and I don't collect data in driver, but write result to db. Is there some other heavy objects that can cause this error?

I checked all logs, and didn't find any warnings or suspicious messages. Last started action was checkpoint. Of course I can increase driver memory limit, but reason of such consumption is still unknown and I'm afraid I have some bottleneck.

Error message:
`Current usage: 4.5 GB of 4.5 GB physical memory used; 6.4 GB of 9.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.`
 And it sends SIGKILL to executors

UPDT:
After some investigations I suppose that problem can be in BroadcastHashJoin. We had a lot of small tables and broadcast join is used to join them, but to broadcast table spark need to materialize it in driver so I disable it by setting `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1`. And looks like memory consumption on driver decreased, and now AM not raising previous error. But on writing result table in DB(postgres) executors stuck on few last task of last stage. In thread dump of executor i see this stuck task:

```
Executor task launch worker for task 635633 RUNNABLE    Lock(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1287601873}), Monitor(java.io.BufferedOutputStream@1935023563}), Monitor(org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl@625626056})
```

It not falling, just  waiting, can this be lock from postgres or something ?